# Using Custom Modules in Python

Tags: python, module, python-import, setuptools, setup.py

I have the following package/directory structure:

```
PythonMDK>>
    README.txt
    setup.py
    PythonMDK>>
        code1.py
        code2.py
        __init__.py
```

And the setup.py file contains the following:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name='PythonMDK',
    version='1.0dev',
    description='Python MDK',
    author='ME',
    author_email='ME@stuff.com',
    packages=['PythonMDK'],
    long_description=open('README.txt').read(),
    url='')
```

How do I now install this and use the classes/functions contained within "code1.py" and "code2.py"? I tried `python setup.py install` and it seemed to work, but now I have a "dist" and "build" folder in the main "PythonMDK" folder and I can seem to use any of the contained functions. So basically what do I have to do now that I have the "setup.py" file in order to make use of those modules?

Comment: Just install via pip: `pip install .` (supposing you're in the folder with the `setup.py` file). Then you can `import PythonMDK`. By the way the same should be possible after doing `python setup.py install`.

Comment: `import PythonMDK` seems to work, but it's not giving me access to any of the functions within the classes within "code1.py" or "code2.py"

Comment: Also why are "dist" and "build" folders created?

Comment: You can either import the desired modules in `__init__` or you can directly import them: `import PythonMDK.code1`.

Comment: Distutils/setuptools use `build` directory for their temporary files; `dist` is for thr resulting source and binary packages. You can clean them with the command `python setup.py clean`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `import PythonMDK` to expose any of your functions in `code1.py`, the file `PythonMDK/__init__.py` must import them like `from code1 import myfunction`. Then you could do `import PythonMDK; PythonMDK.myfunction()`.

See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages, https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#packages, and https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages